# General code for calling a row that works for a matrix or a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector, bigdata

**Is there a general method for calling a row when you do not know whether you'll be referencing a matrix or a vector?**

I want to subset results to those with accuracy greater than .5 and then select the row of the subset with the highest sensitivity. I repeat this process many times in a loop. The problem I'm running into is that in some runs of the model many rows of the results have accuracy greater than .5 and in some runs only one row has accuracy greater than .5.

To call the row with maximum accuracy I've written the code.

```
# Subset matrix to just rows with accuracy greater than .5
acc_ID = which(new_data[,"accuracy"] >= 0.5)
new_data2 = new_data[acc_ID,] 

## Identify which row has the highest sensitivity   
max_sensitivity_ID = which(new_data2[,"sensitivity"] == max(new_data2[,"sensitivity"]))[1]
```

The problem comes from the last line. If there is only one row with accuracy > .5. Then I need to remove the commas.

**Note**: this is a big data situation and I'm not uploading a replicable data example. I figure that someone out there will know a general method for calling a row without replicating the problem.

Comment: You're calling a row, not a column, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop=FALSE` to ensure `new_data2` is always a matrix.

```
new_data2 = new_data[acc_ID,,drop=FALSE]
```